# Is this approach of logging the users out correct?

Tags: php, session

Just began PHP, I have this code and an anchor tag which leads to this file

```
// logout.php 

<?php 
    session_start(); 
    session_destroy(); 
    header('Location: [redirecting link]'); 
    exit(); 
?>
```

Is this okay or there might be some corner cases of doing this? Like, a malicious user won't be able to do anything bad if I use this code, right?

Comment: you crete and session key and them destroy it, is doing actually nothing there...

Comment: @jycr753 Edited the question details.

Comment: You can also insert `$_SESSION = [];` before `session_destroy()` as the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation of why this will log a user out of their session:

```
<?php 
    //this continues the session, or if the user doesn't have a session, will create one.
    session_start(); 

    //destroy their session, they are now "logged out"
    session_destroy(); 

    //this line redirects to a new page, such as the home page, but isn't doing anything to terminate the session.
    header('Location:'.$config['baseurl']); 

    //terminate the script
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: So, what I've done is actually correct, right? There are no vulnerability in this code.

Comment: It's recommendable to call `exit()` after the redirect in order to exit the script (`header()` won't!).

Comment: And that should be it?

Comment: @user3243703, yes it is fine